# Foundation 6 Grid System Doesn't Work

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

Here is my html, I am using the SCSS version:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en" dir="rtl">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Title here</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-3 small-centered columns">3 centered</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-6 large-centered columns">6 centered</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-9 small-centered large-uncentered columns">9 centered</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-11 small-centered columns">11 centered</div>
  </div>
  <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/what-input/dist/what-input.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/foundation-sites/dist/js/foundation.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is what I get:

[image]

**UPDATE** (clarification):
When I inspect the elements, they don't have a row/column class definition, and they are **not centered at all.**

What am I doing wrong?

*Note: I am using the rtl settings. I checked if it broke things, but it still didn't work.*

Comment: What is what you expect to get ?  I see rows on top of each other, seems like what HTML class are calling for ?

Comment: @G-Cyr, I've updated my question, basically they are not centered nor they get the class applied to them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have an `@include foundation-float-classes` or `@include foundation-flex-grid` on your `app.scss`? Maybe you are using only `@include foundation-xy-grid-classes`, where there are no `.row` and `.columns` anymore, only `.grid-x` and `.cell`

Comment: You are totally right! should I move to the grid class? will it work the same way?

Comment: I've switched to the new grid, but you still can work on the legacy one. if you change, you have to write the new classes, i.e.: `.row` is now `.grid-x` and `.columns` = `.cell`, have a look at  https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/xy-grid.html